# Performing Simple Math Operation in VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to perform a simple check on a column of numbers. The check is "if greater than 50 than minus 50 from number" and then I will likely need to do some highlighting/formatting to show that the cell has been manipulated.

The sheet name will change every time, so I don't want to specify the sheet name. Also, the amount of rows will change so I have been using a "range" which loops through each row.

I have a code snippet which works to set the cell value to text, but I can't figure out how to perform a simple math operation on the cell in question.

Here is the code snippet which works to change the value.

```
Public Sub testforfifty()
    Dim rcell As Range, rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("D1:D" & Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    For Each rcell In rng.Cells
        If rcell.Value > 50 Then rcell.Value = "GreaterThan50"
    Next rcell
End Sub
```

What I need is something like this:

```
Public Sub testforfifty()
    Dim rcell As Range, rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("D1:D" & Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    For Each rcell In rng.Cells
        If rcell.Value > 50 Then rcell.Value = rcell - 50
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
    Next rcell
End Sub
```

Comment: What if the value is greater than 100?

Comment: You need to add a check that the cell's contents is numeric, and replace Target on the following line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that some of my cells had text instead of numbers and instead of just moving forward as expected, it stopped and errored out. **The code that is "like what I needed" does work but it doesn't handle non integers and the loop breaks if it gets a cell with text**. Also the highlighting portion isn't working yet, but that's a separate thread/issue that I am still working on myself.

I added this and it work's even if it runs into a cell that isn't a number (and just moves to next cell)

```
   If IsNumeric(rcell.Value) = True Then
```

Answer (score 0):

get a Clng() in there to force to represent cell value as long. but pre warning this will throw error if text is passed!

```
Clng(rcell.Value) > 50
```